# Unsure about using the MVC design pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use the MVC design pattern for my project but I'm sort of unsure about how to decouple my program into the classes.  The first part of my program is a Login screen which requires the user to enter a their username and password and a start button which checks the details, and there is a button to go to a page where you can add a new user.  So I was thinking for my MVC design:

loginpanelView : Just the GUI with the text boxes, labels, buttons etc

loginpanelController:
-  implement the actionlistener for the start button here and have a reference to the method checkLogin
-  implement actionlistener for add user button here and have reference to a method which switches the panels

loginModel:
-  defines the actual method which checks the login

switchpanelModel:
-  defines a method which creates a cardlayout system and switches the panels

My understanding is that the controller just makes very general references to what needs to be done i.e. sort of what the user wants to happen, then the model defines the exact method of how to handle this?  Would someone mind verifying/ correcting my understanding please?  I've read a lot about this design pattern but unfortunately I still don't feel like I have a clear understanding of it.  Any help would be much appreciated!

p.s.  Sorry!  I forgot to include that I'm programming in Java

Comment: I would probably help to add a language you are writing it in, as people who have used the language can be more descriptive about the actual implementation than the abstract how-to of MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sometimes helps to think of MVC in terms of dependencies.

The model repesents what your application does.  It has no dependencies on anything.  It is what makes your application unique.

The view displays information to the user.  This information comes from the model.  Therefore, the view has a dependency on the model.

The controller's function is to accept input from the user, dispatch that request to the appropriate model functionality, and (normally) accept the return value and supply it for a view to render.  Thus, the controller is usually very tightly coupled to the view(s) that it serves.  It also has dependencies on the model.

In this case, the model is your authentication scheme. (In reality, this is not all that much of a model but an entry point in your application, your overall model is something like "process payments", "generate report", "request to create widget", etc.)

You have two views, one to enter authentication information and a second for when an authentication succeeds.  The first really does not have any model information, it is solely to collect input (however its design will be based on whatever the authentication model needs, so there is still a dependency here).  The second will undoubtedly display a list of available features your application offers or display a landing page etc.

It is the controller's responsibility to mediate these interactions.  Therefore, information sent from the first view is received by the controller, dispatched to the authentication model, authentication succeeds or fails, and then the controller chooses the appropriate view to render based on the result.

Answer (score 0):

With such a basic "functional design" it's hard to help you exactly, but you might want to think more about the big picture about what you want.

- A user model - database model for a user. Contains a "check login"
  method
- A login-page View - Form, layout etc
- A login controller - Gets the stuff out of the form, tries to log someone in with the method from the user object, and create said user
  object

The page view/controllers can be split up ofcourse in several sub-parts, but this might not be a bad place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that LoginModel and SwitchPaneModel are not models at all. Model is what you store somewhere. So you will have UserModel and PaneModel. And your controller will implement switchPane method and login method. It's good idea to decouple this method in some separate classes there are lots of methods to perform this task. But I strongly recommend you to find ready solution. Don't invent the bicycle.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html). This is a special case of MVC called Passive View. The first important idea is that the view and the model do not communicate with each other at all. The view only tells the controller about events, and the controller manipulates both the view and the model. A controller can even create new controllers and views (such as for complex modal dialogs). And finally, the model does not communicate with anyone!

So you have the right idea: your loginpanelController listens for button events from the loginpanelView, and then calls the right methods in the model to set the data and validate it.

I think one place you may be having a problem with is switchpanelModel. I don't think you need this. If your loginpanelView is the view with the cards in it, then your loginpanelController should be the one switching the cards.

I think models should be restricted to methods working with its own data, but must have no reference to any GUI element anywhere. Models do not drive the program; controllers do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then thinking in terms of 'defining' a method, perhaps it is better to think in terms of what is being [encapsulated](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2001/jw-0518-encapsulation.html?page=9).

For example, *loosely*, in MVC a view encapsulates *primarily* the user interface of your program (a login form), a model encapsulates some part of your domain logic (password authentication) and a controller encapsulates the logic that connects a view with a model (it depends there are variation of MVC architecture). The controller is often to some extent coupled to a view (especially if you start adding overtly specific ActionListeners etc) however the model should be quite reusable/exchangable (changing how you validate should not mean you have to change any view/controller that uses it)